# Linux unzip preserve case?

Tags: linux, web, zip, gzip, tar

Working on a web site.  A number of third party javascript libraries use mixed-case in their files and folders.

I am working on a windows system.

When ready to upload from my local windows XAMPP environment to my linux hosting, I use 7zip to create a zip file of my site.  I use 7zip's -xr! feature to skip certain directories like my .git repository.

I FTP the resulting .zip file to my server and use the server's "unzip" function to explode it.  All my files are there but *they are all changed to lowercase!*

This kills the website as the third party libraries that are mixed-case are no longer found.

I've tried unzip -C but that did not seem to do anything.

I also look in the archive prior to uploading and on windows, all the file name cases are preserved.

Tried using GNU32's windows tar but the --exclude function is not allowing me to skip the .git directories.

I need some help in the form of:

- How to use unzip in linux such that is preserves case (googled until hairless, but no love found...)
- How to use tar on windows such that it excludes particular directories
- How to use something else to achieve my goal.  I honestly don't care what it is... I'm downloading CYGWIN right now to see if it'll help at all.  I may end up installing Linux in a virtual box just to try tar-gz from a virtual machine actually running linux but would REALLY rather avoid that hassle every time I want to pack up a pretty simple archive.

Zip works fine for packing, but unpacking is not kosher.

Answer (score 0):

Use tar's `--exclude-vcs` option:

```
--exclude-vcs
    exclude version control system directories
```

Example:

```
tar --exclude-vcs czf foo.tar.gz foo
```

or for a *.tar.bz2 archive

```
tar --exclude-vcs cjf foo.tar.bz2 foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `unzip -U file.zip`; this might work if you have an old version of `unzip`. Otherwise, post the output of `unzip -v` and `unzip -l file.zip`.